# mapred.JobClient: Error reading task output http:... when running hadoop from Cygwin on Windows OS

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin, mahout

I was running the "Generating vectors from documents" sample from the book "**Mahout** in Action" from **Cygwin** on **Windows**. 
**Hadoop is started only on the local machine.**

Below is my running command:

**$ bin/mahout seq2sparse -i reuters-seqfiles/ -o reuters-vectors -ow**

But it shows below java.io.IOException, anyone knows what causes this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
Running on hadoop, using HADOOP_HOME=my_hadoop_path
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=my_hadoop_conf_path
13/05/13 18:38:03 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No seq2sparse.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
13/05/13 18:38:03 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Maximum n-gram size is: 1
13/05/13 18:38:03 INFO common.HadoopUtil: Deleting reuters-vectors
13/05/13 18:38:04 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Minimum LLR value: 1.0
13/05/13 18:38:04 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Number of reduce tasks: 1
13/05/13 18:38:04 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
13/05/13 18:38:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201305131836_0001
13/05/13 18:38:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/13 18:38:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201305131836_0001_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:418)

13/05/13 18:38:15 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://namenode_address:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201305131836_0001_m_000003_0&filter=stdout
13/05/13 18:38:15 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://namenode_address:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201305131836_0001_m_000003_0&filter=stderr
13/05/13 18:38:21 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201305131836_0001_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:418)
```

Below is the running log of tasktracker:

```
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: ProcessTree implementation is missing on this system. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: IndexCache created with max memory = 10485760
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201305141049_0001_m_000002_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201305141049_0001_m_000002_0
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201305141049_0001_m_000002_0
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201305141049_0001_m_1036671648
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201305141049_0001_m_1036671648 spawned.
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201305141049_0001_m_1036671648 exited. Number of tasks it ran: 0
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: attempt_201305141049_0001_m_000002_0 Child Error
java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:418)
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: attempt_201305141049_0001_m_000002_0 done; removing files.
 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the whatever log you have posted, it seems you haven't set the `HADOOP_HOME=my_hadoop_path` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=my_hadoop_conf_path`. 
You need to put those directory paths for e.g. `HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/conf`.

If this is not the case, try with `bin/mahout` only and check if seq2sparse is present somewhere in the list. This line clearly states that it's not found: `driver.MahoutDriver: No seq2sparse.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only`.

Comment: This is not the root couse. I have set both HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_CONF_DIR.

Comment: Can you do a  `bin/mahout`, edit your question with the output?

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the problem by simply re-installing and configuring Hadoop and mahout. Now it works all right. Thank you anyway. :-)